# SCP / Bash Echo the files that were copied?

Tags: bash, scp

I'm using SCP command to copy files using a bash script. How do I echo the file names that were copied successfully?

Comment: sharing some of your code would help you not to get negative votes. Also reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use $? to access the return value of the last command. Check the man page for scp to verify, but I think a return value of zero means success. A non-zero value means some kind of failure.

```
scp "fromHere" hostname:"toThere"
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ];
then
    echo "SUCCESS"
else
    echo "FAIL"
fi
```

OR

```
for gzfile in $LOCALDMPDIR/*.gz
do
  /usr/bin/scp -P 2222 -i $KEYFILE $gzfile foobar@$1:$TGTDIR      2>>/var/log/scperror.log \
  && echo "$gzfile is done." \
  || echo "scp error: $gzfile"
done
```